# Re-instated the azure subscription by removing the spending limit

Tags: azure

I have re-instated my azure subscription by removing the spending limit. On the portal, all web sites are running, the site http://prosystem.azurewebsites.net is running but I get an error 404 when I try to get my personal domain http://www.prosystem.fr
I looks like the re-instated process has not reactivated the dns. I have tried to cancel and 
reinstalled my personnel domain, but nothing.
I have open a ticket concerning invoicing, but the MS guy said it's a tech issue but my azure subscription is "for visual studio professionnal" so I cannot open "technical ticket".
Any idea to help me.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen and posted an answer here.  [Microsoft Azure Websites : Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164209/microsoft-azure-websites-error-404/25164210#25164210)

The answer was to check the "WEB HOSTING PLAN MODE". Microsoft reverts that to Free when the spending limit is triggered. If you are using a SSL certificate or any other feature requiring "Basic or Standard" - the non-descriptive and incorrect error of Website Not Found will be displayed.